# ArrayOutOfBoundException when populate result in jTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I tried to do a search system using java swing :

```java
    public void search(ActionEvent e){
    String textEntered=getJTextField_searchField().getText();
    if(textEntered.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a word");
    }
    else{
        kioskViewevents viewEvents=new kioskViewevents(textEntered);
        if(viewEvents.searchContent() == true){
            getJScrollPane().setVisible(false);
            getJScrollPane_search();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No result found");
        }


    }
}
```

This method will be perform after search button is on click. It will hide the previous table then replace with another table. Then I populate the search results inside the table.

```java
    public void SetUpJTable_search(){
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTableSearch.getModel();

    String[] data = new String[5];
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select event_ID,event_Price,event_Title,event_Time,event_Date FROM crossEvent WHERE event_Title='"+ textEntered +"'";

    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            data[0] = resultSet.getString("event_ID");
            data[1] = resultSet.getString("event_Price");
            data[2] = resultSet.getString("event_Title");
            data[3] = resultSet.getString("event_Time");
            data[4] = resultSet.getString("event_Date");
            tableModel.addRow(data);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

I set up my Search table :

```java
    private JTable getJTable_search() {
    String header[] = { "Event ID", "Price", "Title","Time","Date"};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
    jTableSearch.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(100);

    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(200);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(300);

    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(300);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(400);

    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(100);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(100);

    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(100);
    jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(100);


    jTableSearch.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    jTableSearch.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
    jTableSearch.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    jTableSearch.setRowHeight(50);
    jTableSearch.setBounds(new Rectangle(97, 157, 800, 450));
    jTableSearch.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    return jTableSearch;
}
```

My Scroll Pane for search table :

```java
    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane_search(){
    if (jScrollPane_search == null) {
        jScrollPane_search = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane_search.setBounds(new Rectangle(75, 180, 800, 450));
        jScrollPane_search.setViewportView(getJTable_search());
    }
    SetUpJTable_search();
    return jScrollPane_search;
}
```

This whole junk of codes is to populate the table with data existing in database before performing search :

```java
    private JTable getJTable() {
    String header[] = { "Event ID", "Price", "Title","Time","Date"};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
    // Hide Topic ID
    jTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(100);

    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(200);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(300);

    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(300);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(400);

    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(100);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(100);

    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(100);
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(100);

    jTable.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    jTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
    jTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    jTable.setRowHeight(50);
    jTable.setBounds(new Rectangle(97, 157, 800, 450));
    jTable.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    return jTable;
}

    public void SetUpJTable() {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();

    String[] data = new String[5];
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select event_ID,event_Price,event_Title,event_Time,event_Date FROM crossEvent";

    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    tableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            data[0] = resultSet.getString("event_ID");
            data[1] = resultSet.getString("event_Price");
            data[2] = resultSet.getString("event_Title");
            data[3] = resultSet.getString("event_Time");
            data[4] = resultSet.getString("event_Date");

            tableModel.addRow(data);
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

However, I got an error message which is :

```java
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
at kioskViewevents.ui.ViewEventsUI.getJTable_search(ViewEventsUI.java:158)
at kioskViewevents.ui.ViewEventsUI.getJScrollPane_search(ViewEventsUI.java:201)
at kioskViewevents.ui.ViewEventsUI.search(ViewEventsUI.java:330)
at kioskViewevents.ui.ViewEventsUI$4.actionPerformed(ViewEventsUI.java:315)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the stacktrace as you'll know exactly where the exception has occured. The exact line in fact

Comment: pls. post full stacktrace.

Comment: Please add the code for `getJTable_search(ViewEventsUI.java:158)`

Comment: @Newbies Stop posting bits and pieces of code. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I edited the whole junk of codes already

Comment: @Newbies You don't understand the code you have posted not enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which one is the line 158 in `ViewEvents.java` (as you haven't mentioned it), but the stacktrace and remaining code tells me that the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is because you're trying to access a column like below:

```
    jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(100);  // Not sure which column is the issue
```

And you don't have those many columns in the `vector` i.e. `jTable.getColumnModel()`. You're trying to access an element beyond the size of the vector.

The exact problem on why/where this issue occurs could be different, but this is where you should start looking at.

Comment: Line 158  : jTableSearch.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100); But I thought I retrieve 5 data from database so I need to set the width for 5 column in table?

Comment: In that case, your table model doesn't have any columns. If you check with `getColumnCount()` on your JTable, it should return 0.

Comment: So is there any way to fix this? Because these codes work perfectly for my other tables to display the thread content of forum

Comment: There is. You need to set up your IDE and debugger. I would start with checking the code piece where I create the columns.

Comment: Now there is no errors anymore. But the table which after users perform search does not showing. Is it possible to do in such way : I display all data in database using first table. After user perform search, i use the where clause in second table and hide the first table in java?